# VBA - Naming multiple ranges according to cell values

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I'm trying to name intervals in every worksheet according to the content of a specific cell in each worksheet. I've looked up many ways of naming the ranges, whoever none uses the content of a cell as a name. This is what I have (but it doesn't work):

```
Sub NameRanges()

Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer
Dim r As String

     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count


     For I = 5 To WS_Count

        r = Worksheets(I).Range("A2")
        Names.Add Name:="r", RefersTo:=Worksheets(I).Range("B6:B10000")


     Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: `Names.Add Name:=r`? Variables don't belong inside quotes.

Answer (score 1):

To name a sheet simply use its `.Name` property like this:

```
Sub NameSheets()
    Dim i As Integer
    With ActiveWorkbook
        For i = 5 To .Sheets.Count
            .Sheets(i).Name = .Sheets(i).Range("A2").Value
        Next i
    End with
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @SuperSymmetry, however it's still not working. I get a message saying that there's a syntax error regarding this part:

Worksheets(i).Range("B6:B10000").Name = Worksheets(i).Range("A2").Value

Comment: Most likely because you don't have valid names in A2 of these worksheet. When it gives you the error, what name are you trying to give this range?

Comment: I'm actually trying to name 100 different sheets in the same workbook, each with a different name (in cell A2 of each sheet).

Comment: Why would you then say "I'm trying to name intervals **in every** worksheet". And why would you name (or use) a prcedure `NameRanges`. and make the name `ReferTo` `Range("B6:B10000")`. And why would you say in the question "I've looked up many ways of naming the ranges". Please make sure you understand what you're saying and write what you mean, otherwise, you're wasting the time of people that are trying to help you. Anyway, I updated my answer

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help, I really appreciate that! 
I misspoke on my latest comment, sorry about that. I have to name the ranges "B6:B10000" in every sheet according to the name in cell "A2" of that specific sheet. So it's the ranges I have to name, not the sheets